# Python threading.thread.start() doesn't return control to main thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I'm trying to a program that executes a piece of code in such a way that the user can stop its execution at any time without stopping the main program. I thought I could do this using threading.Thread, but then I ran the following code in IDLE (Python 3.3):

```
from threading import *
import math
def f():
    eval("math.factorial(1000000000)")
t = Thread(target = f)
t.start()
```

The last line doesn't return: I eventually restarted the shell. Is this a consequence of the Global Interpreter Lock, or am I doing something wrong? I didn't see anything specific to this problem in the threading documentation (http://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

I tried to do the same thing using a process:

```
from multiprocessing import *
import math
def f():
    eval("math.factorial(1000000000)")

p = Process(target = f)
p.start()
p.is_alive()
```

The last line returns False, even though I ran it only a few seconds after I started the process! Based on my processor usage, I am forced to conclude that the process never started in the first place. Can somebody please explain what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Thread.start() never returns! Could this have something to do with the C implementation of the math library?

As [@eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138190/python-threading-thread-start-doesnt-return-control-to-main-thread#comment33634685_22138509) pointed out in the comment: [math.factorial() is implemented as a C function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d37f963394aa/Modules/mathmodule.c#l1087) that doesn't release GIL so no other Python code may run until it returns.

Note: `multiprocessing` version should work as is: each Python process has its own GIL.

---

`factorial(1000000000)` has hundreds millions of digits. Try `import time; time.sleep(10)` as dummy calculation instead.

If you have issues with multithreaded code in IDLE then try the same code from the command line, to make sure that the error persists.

If `p.is_alive()` returns `False` after `p.start()` is already called then it might mean that there is an error in `f()` function e.g., `MemoryError`.

On my machine, `p.is_alive()` returns `True` and one of cpus is at 100% if I paste your code from the question into Python shell.

Unrelated: remove wildcard imports such as `from multiprocessing import *`. They may shadow other names in your code so that you can't be sure what a given name means e.g., `threading` could define `eval` function (it doesn't but it could) with a similar but different semantics that might break your code silently.

> I want my program to be able to handle ridiculous inputs from the user gracefully

If you pass user input directly to `eval()` then the user can do *anything*.

> Is there any way to get a process to print, say, an error message without constructing a pipe or other similar structure?

It is an ordinary Python code:

```
print(message) # works
```

The difference is that if several processes run `print()` then the output might be garbled. You could use a lock to synchronize `print()` calls.

Comment: Your suggestion about time.sleep() returns as I would expect. However, I chose an absurd calculation like factorial(1000000000) because I want my program to be able to handle ridiculous inputs from the user gracefully. This code performs exactly the same way in the shell. Is there any way to get a process to print, say, an error message without constructing a pipe or other similar structure?

Comment: @user3372045: I've answered your questions from the comment. Also your multiprocessing code works on my machine as expected (`p.is_alive() is True`)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the user can do anything". My plan was to handle the eval() statement in a separate thread of control, leaving the main thread unharmed if something goes wrong there. This doesn't work if Thread.start() never returns! Could this have something to do with the C implementation of the math library? If so, I could rewrite operations like factorial in pure Python. Much slower, but worth it if I can interrupt the operation.