# Bug in Python? threading.Thread.start() does not always return

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, boost-python

I have a tiny Python script which (in my eyes) makes `threading.Thread.start()` behave unexpectedly since it does not return immediately.

Inside a thread I want to call a method from a `boost::python` based object which will not return immediately.

To do so I wrap the object/method like this:

```
import threading
import time
import my_boostpython_lib

my_cpp_object = my_boostpython_lib.my_cpp_class()

def some_fn():
    # has to be here - otherwise .start() does not return
    # time.sleep(1)  
    my_cpp_object.non_terminating_fn() # blocks

print("%x: 1" % threading.get_ident())
threading.Thread(target=some_fn).start()
print("%x: 2" % threading.get_ident())  # will not always be called!!
```

And everything works fine as long as I **run some code before** `my_cpp_object.non_terminating_fn()`. If I don't, `.start()` will block the same way as calling `.run()` directly would.

Printing just a line before calling the `boost::python` function is not enough, but e.g. printing two lines or calling `time.sleep()` makes `start()` return immediately as expected.

Can you explain this behavior? How would I avoid this (apart from calling `sleep()` before calling a `boost::python` function)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior is (as in most cases when you believe in a bug in an interpreter/compiler) not a bug in Python but a **race condition** covering the behavior you have to expect because of the Python **GIL** (also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138190/python-threading-thread-start-doesnt-return-control-to-main-thread)).

As soon as the non-Python function `my_cpp_object.non_terminating_fn()` has been started the GIL doesn't get released until it returns and keeps the interpreter from executing any other command.

So `time.sleep(1)` doesn't help here anyway because the code following `my_cpp_object.non_terminating_fn()` would not be executed until the GIL gets released.

In case of `boost::python` and of course in case you can modify the C/C++ part you can release the GIL manually as described [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/HowTo).

A small example (from the link above) could look like this (in the boost::python wrapper code)

```
class scoped_gil_release {
public:
    inline scoped_gil_release() {
        m_thread_state = PyEval_SaveThread();
    }

    inline ~scoped_gil_release() {
        PyEval_RestoreThread(m_thread_state);
        m_thread_state = NULL;
    }

private:
    PyThreadState * m_thread_state;
};

int non_terminating_fn_wrapper() {
    scoped_gil_release scoped;
    return non_terminating_fn();
}
```

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18648366/1053968) provides a generic way to specify an exposed function should run without the GIL.

Comment: I don't exactly know what you're trying to say.. this snippet is just intended to show how to release the GIL in case you run a native function in parallel to the Python interpreter

Comment: I was just linking to a nonintrusive and generic way too accomplish the same thing.

Comment: This was a hard to explain misunderstanding on my side :) Didn't see the link (bad monitor!)