# How to wrap a message loop with callbacks using boost::python (keeping the GIL in mind)

Tags: python, c++, wrapper, boost-python, gil

I want to wrap an existing C++ library which involves a **blocking message loop** and **calling handler functions** for **Python** using **boost::python**. E.g.:

```
import my_boostpython_lib

def my_handler_fn():
    do_something()

md = my_boostpython_lib.message_dispatcher()

# calls a C++ object method and blocks
md.run_message_loop(my_handler_fn)
```

Calling a Python function from C++ is no problem but the message loop needs to release the `GIL` since otherwise it would block the whole Python interpreter (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31456483), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138190) and a related [boost ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7836))

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8011153/1668622) it's important to lock the `GIL` again before calling a Python function.

In principle this sounds comprehensible to me but I wonder if there are any elegant solutions out there which show how this can be done.
E.g. it would be very nice if I had to modify the boost::python wrapper only (instead of altering the library I want to wrap)

Do you know any **working example** which involves **boost::python**, **callbacks** using an object oriented approach (and maybe blocking functions which release the `GIL`) where I can copy some best practices from?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20828366/1053968) demonstrates how to safely wrap a Python callback in a handler and covers some subtle details, such as GIL management during copy-construction and destruction.